# "dzil test" isn't copying my perltidyrc file

Tags: perl, dist-zilla

For a [Perl module I'm writing](https://github.com/Ovid/moosex-extreme), I use `Test::PerlTidy`. My tests pass just fine. However, I'm also using [dzil](https://dzil.org/). The `t/perltidy.t` tests pass when I run them, but `dzil test` doesn't appear to be copying the perltidyrc file into the `./build` directory, so the tests fail there.

Thus, to get the CI passing, I'm converting that to a `TODO` test until I can figure out what I missed.

How do I get `dzil test` to copy that file over?

See also:

- https://github.com/Ovid/moosex-extreme/pull/2
- https://github.com/Ovid/moosex-extreme/blob/main/dist.ini
- https://github.com/Ovid/moosex-extreme/blob/main/t/perltidy.t

Answer (score 1):

It was a typo in my `perltidy.t` test. I referred to `perltidy`, not `perltidyrc`. My tests ordinarily picked it up because it could see my `.perltidyrc` file, but `dzil test` doesn't copy that over. The tests however, were supposed to point to `./t/perltidyrc`.